# Php file that does not parse includes

Tags: php, parsing, include

My goal is to have a file with the following html/php created on the server automatically
which it does do, however it includes the php includes as well so when the page is build it includes everything that is in the include as well.

I would want `include("../includes/right.html");` to be left alone
in the page that is generated,but I want other php variables to be parsed.

```
<?php
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>

<?php echo $name; ?>

test text line one

<?php include("../includes/right.html"); ?>

test text line two

<?php
// Putting content buffer into file //
file_put_contents('mypage.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

Comment: Escape the `<?php include ... ?>` so that PHP does not interpret it as PHP.

Comment: hey matt, not sure what you mean by escape it?

Comment: another solution would be to read the file as a string by a seperate php script and just echo it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straight from the PHP manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc
This is called nowdoc syntax and comes with PHP 5.3. It's generally the best practice for something like this.

```
echo <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should not print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

anything between 'EOT' and EOT; will be rendered on the page as text with no parsing done whatsoever.

Comment: Many thanks buddy, was exactly what i was looking for. thanks to everyone else as well for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape that line as HTML, so it's not passed through the PHP parser, e.g.

```
<?php
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>

<?php echo $name; ?>

test text line one

&lt;?php include(&quot;../includes/right.html&quot;); ?&gt;

test text line two

<?php
// Putting content buffer into file //
file_put_contents('mypage.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```